# 3D object recognition

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, augmented-reality

I am developing AR solution.

Use Case - User can point the camera at a 3D object (photocopy machine) from any angle and it should give the pose of the 3D object.

Though I have tried Vuforia with the help of model target generator - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0CIWhxf94wk, but no luck.

Then I tried VisionLib - https://visionlib.com/ it worked but to an extent, I meant you have to align it with the image in HUD.

Then I took a different approach and started exploring machine learning options. 
I also found that I can use CNN - Conventional Neural Network.

But is this the right approach, or I should try OpenCV to write my own solution?

Or is there any other approach that I should take.

I also found about YOLOv2 - https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/, but I am not sure that it will give me pose or not.

So far what I am able to understand is that I should use CNN to detect the object in camera frame and then with the help of OpenCV find its pose.
The above approach sounds simple but needs some heavy lifting.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Conv networks sounds like the right approach. This is probably a paper you should read: https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.5928

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convolutional Neural Network are probably the best approach to your problem.

With CNN, you solve the problem of detecting specific objects (in your case, a photocopy machine). The steps needed are:

1. Choose a model (SSD, Faster-RCNN, R-FCN, YOLOv2...)
2. Download pre-trained weights for the model you chose (process known as Transfer Learning)
3. Take hundreds of photos of your photocopy machine and annotate them
4. Fine tune your model training it with your own dataset (this will require to modify the net)
5. Evaluate your model to see if it predicts well (i.e. detect photocopy machine where it actually is in the current frame)
6. If no, consider using more images for your dataset or try to adapt parameters of your net (learning rate, number of training epochs, number of layers, optimizer algorithm...)

**BUT**

The net you will end up with will not give you any information regarding the pose of the photocopy machine. It will just say: YES, it is in the frame or NO, it isn't here.

A possible workaround might be to encode (alias annotate) pose estimation information for each image of your dataset (you get this info from your device's IMU). Then you need to modify your net to take into account this info. This means:

1. Modify your input layer in order to provide additional info (this only during training phase)
2. Modify your output layer in order to output pose estimation
3. Modify the inner structure of the net so that, during test phase it perform regression of the pose estimation

Not a simple task, really. Hope it helps.

Good luck!

Comment: Hey hi, Thanks for the details.

Comment: If it helped you, could you please mark it as accepted answer? Thanks!